# Format text to bold

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have one xml file and I am reading data from it using indesign java scripting.
At one point I got stuck whenever I get text in xml enclosed within `'<b>'INDIA'</b>'` then should get converted to bold **INDIA** font for after executing java script.
Is there any way in indesign java script to convert that specific text into bold or other font style.

I don't have coded anything but below is the code which I found on Web but also not working

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var frame = doc.pages[0].textFrames.add({
geometricBounds: [700, 50, 500, 200]
});

var bold = doc.characterStyles.add({name:"Bold", fontStyle:"Bold"});
var none = doc.characterStyles.itemByName("[None]");

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(none);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = "I really like";

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(bold);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = " walking to the park";

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(none);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = " and eating icecream";
```

Comment: where is your code in witch you try to parse it correctly?

Comment: Please find updated

Answer (score 1):

Your sample only needed a little modification to be effective. The default character and paragraph styles always have the index set to 0 as they can't be nor moved nor removed.

So you may try this :

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
```

var frame = doc.pages[0].textFrames.add({
geometricBounds: [700, 50, 500, 200]
});

var bold = doc.characterStyles.itemByName ("Bold");
!bold.isValid && bold = doc.characterStyles.add({name:"Bold", fontStyle:"Bold"});

**var none = doc.characterStyles[0]; //similmar to "[None]"**

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(none);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = "I really like";

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(bold);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = " walking to the park";

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().applyCharacterStyle(none);

frame.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = " and eating icecream";

Here you are

[image: A demonstration of applying bold to text through script]